# How to access image from upload tmp folder on apache

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, global-variables

I am creating image with imagejpeg php command and my question is how to access it when it is saved to tmp folder on the apache server?

I cannot use ../../tmp notation because for accessing it it eeded http protocol not file protocol. I tried with $_ENV and $_FILES variables but they are empty arrays.

How to access the upload folder with some php command, is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`rename`](http://fr.php.net/rename) function to move it whenever you need to be, in the webroot if you want to make it public.

Regarding, the `$_ENV` and `$_FILES`, the first one is used to store environment variables PATH etc, the second is used when a files is uploaded. You can review this [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: yes the problem is not saving the image, the problem is how to access it with with http address, is it possible?

Comment: @Vlad: to access it using the webserver, it would have been place under the webroot directory, so first you have to move the file away from the temp directory, does it make sense?

Comment: yes, I undestand, if it is not under www root directory it is not accessible. thanks